# How can I show include model's specific column in an array? Sequelize PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two models which are Licences and Items.

```
models.Licences.hasMany(models.Items, {
    foreignKey: 'licenceId',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
});
```

Licence can has many `Items`.

`Items` model has `licenceId` and `description`.

```
 try {
      return await db.Licences.findAll({
        order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        attributes: [
          'id',
          'desc',
          'version',
          [db.Sequelize.col('Items.description'), 'itemDesc']
        ],
        include: [
          {
            model: db.Items,
            attributes: []
          },
        ],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
 }
```

This method return only one item description. However I want to return response as;

```
[
   {
      id: 1,
      desc: 'LicenceOne',
      itemDesc: [
       "exone",
        "extwo"
      ]
    }
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please share the current response log.

Comment: [{id: 1, desc: 'LicenceOne', itemDesc: 'extwo'}]

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below way and make changes.

```js
 try {
      return await db.Licences.findAll({
        order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        attributes: [
          'id',
          'desc',
          'version',
        ],
        include: [
          {
            model: db.Items,
            attributes: ['description'],
          },
        ],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
 }
```

But you will get the below output. Not exactly how you want but you can reprocess all array object and have all description as a array of string in each object. Sequelize will not automatically process the array directly as per what I know.

```js
[
    {
        id: 1,
        desc: 'LicenceOne'
        version: '1.1.1',
        Items: [
            {
                description: 'the desctiption 1'
            },
            {
                description: 'the desctiption 2'
            },
            {
                description: 'the desctiption 3'
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        // and on...
    }
]
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this way which is same your code and it return response as your answer. I hope, there is no way to get this response with sequelize. It can be solved with js reduce functions.

Comment: Yes, you can reiterate the array and reduce it to array of strings